# Prove that a series converges if $|a_n|<1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given a succession of real numbers $\{a_n\}_n$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I would like to prove, or find a counterexample, of the fact that if $|a_n|<1$ from a $n$ on then, then $\begin{aligned} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n)^n \end{aligned}$ converges.

Someone could give me a hand? Thank you!

Comment: This is incorrect. Take $a(n) = 1-\frac{1}{n}$, then $a(n)^n \to e^{-1}$. Thus the series cannot converge.

Comment: $a_n = 2^{-1/n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a(n)=1-\frac1n$. Then $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a(n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=e^{-1}\neq 0.
$$
Therefore the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)^n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Dear @Mundron Schmidt I have a limit question, but my latex knowledge is so bad..Can you help me for ask??thank you so much.

Comment: @MathLife: How can I help you?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $$a_n =(1-1/n)$$ is such that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n^n = e^{-1}$$ which is not even converging to zero. Hence the series $\sum a_n^n$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example : Let $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $(a_n)^n$ doesn't tend to zero.

(with the sum starting at $n\geq 1$)